# Why some Docker CLI subcommands have asterisks?

Tags: docker

In Docker Desktop, some CLI subcommands have asterisks (*), e.g.:

```sh
$ docker           

Usage:  docker [OPTIONS] COMMAND
(...)
Management Commands:
  builder     Manage builds
  buildx*     Build with BuildKit (Docker Inc., v0.5.1-docker)
  compose*    Docker Compose (Docker Inc., 2.0.0-beta.4)
(...)
  scan*       Docker Scan (Docker Inc., v0.8.0)
(...)
```

I understand these are plugins (namely [buildx](https://github.com/docker/buildx), [compose](https://github.com/docker/compose-cli) and [scan](https://github.com/docker/scan-cli-plugin)), but adding the asterisk makes no sense to me.

Why is an asterisk added to the command name and where is the source code that adds the asterisk?

Comment: A side effect of this, using Oh My Zsh's Docker plugin, the auto-completion is weird. Typing "docker comp" followed by tab, gets completed to "docker compose\* "

Comment: That could be because zsh is guessing autocompletion patterns from usage message. I believe that if you install [this](https://github.com/docker/cli/blob/master/contrib/completion/zsh/_docker) completion file from Docker's cli repo it should complete sub-commands (including plugin provided ones) properly without asterisk.

Comment: The asterisk in the autocompletion was fixed in the this pull request: https://github.com/docker/cli/pull/3540

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Asterisk (`*`) is a decoration that shows these sub-commands are provided by plugins and not part of `docker` cli itself. It helps user to distinguish between built-in and plugin sub-commands. Same for provider and version of plugin in brackets which is only shown for plugins.

Asterisk itself is just "marker" and not part of the sub-command name (so to run `buildx` command will be just `docker buildx ...`). Plugins are standalone binaries which `docker` cli finds at runtime and their source code (if available) usually lives in their own repository - for e.g. `buildx` [here](https://github.com/docker/buildx).

Function in the `docker-ce` codebase that decorates all plugins with star is [decoratedName()](https://github.com/docker/docker-ce/blob/018d40d7adde3323595b01a86f2add82fdbab7d2/components/cli/cli/cobra.go#L261) in `components/cli/cli/cobra.go`. That function is then used in [*usage message* template](https://github.com/docker/docker-ce/blob/018d40d7adde3323595b01a86f2add82fdbab7d2/components/cli/cli/cobra.go#L352) which is rendered when listing all sub-commands.

NOTE: Links to codebase above are pointing to `docker-ce` repository (same function in Docker `cli` repository is [here](https://github.com/docker/cli/blob/4a6fe51157bf0199a933f44d1da09685f48fd8dd/cli/cobra.go#L261) and template [here](https://github.com/docker/cli/blob/4a6fe51157bf0199a933f44d1da09685f48fd8dd/cli/cobra.go#L352)).

Comment: I understand they're plugins. I'm questioning why is the asterisk added to the command name and where is the source code that adds the asterisk.

Comment: @nuno sorry missed your update, original post was a bit ambigous. Updated my answer with relevant pointers to the `docker` codebase. Hope that helps and answers your question.